# How to align two span elements separately but in same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on aligning two `span` elements should be present in same line but have separated as shown in below. The code i am using is below.

If I do not use `float:right` the both texts are coming in single line with attaching one each other.

If I use `float:right;` they are not aligning in same line, having some misalignment between them.

with `float:right;` the result will be this

[image: ss]

without `float:right;` the result will be this

[image: ss1]

Please give me suggestions for this

```css
.clearSpan {
    color:  $alt-dark-blue;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.saveSpan {
    color:  $alt-dark-blue;
 clear : both;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div> 
   <span class="saveSpan" >Save as Default Filters</span>
   <span class="clearSpan" >Clear All Filters</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thats really easy, put both spans inside a block element .e.g. <p> <span> </span> </p>

then apply to one of them `display: inline-block` and add padding or margin  to it.

Clean and Easy no need to use floats / flex box or any other hacky way.

Comment: @David Strada - It Works when i use padding-left:__px;  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` for that

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey
}
span {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="saveSpan">Save as Default Filters</span>
  <span class="clearSpan">Clear All Filters</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do:

```
.clearSpan {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

or

```
.saveSpan {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

That should separate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a style for your span tags as,

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```